# Present Simple and Present Continous

Tags: present-tense

There are 2 examples.

1) *I am visiting a psychologist.* (but perhaps I am not visiting a psychologist at the time of speaking)

2) *I visit a psychologist.*

What is the difference between these 2 examples, if they are correct?

I ask because of this example:

*Kate wants to work in Italy, so she’s learning Italian.* (but perhaps she isn’t learning Italian at the time of speaking)

I would suggest an example to this sentence, but I guess ***Kate learns Italian.*** sounds a little strange. Help pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Present Continuous

> I am visiting a psychologist.

This implies you're visiting a psychologist right now.

However, if you say `I am visiting a psychologist today` - it's totally correct since **Present Continuous** should be used for future events along with time adverb. Please read more in *Collins Dictionary* [here](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/the-present-continuous-tense)

Another use case for **Present Continuous** is:

> a temporary activity, even if it is not happening at the time when we
>   are talking.

Obviously, you can use *I'm visiting a psychologist* in this context too. For example, here's a quote from [Financial Times](https://www.ft.com/content/cc3bedac-0510-11e7-ace0-1ce02ef0def9):

> “I’m seeing a psychologist because I can’t sleep,” she said.

She implies it will take some time before she can sleep again (she will be seeing a doctor during this period of time). Then, she will probably stop seeing a psychologist.

### Present Simple

> I visit a psychologist.

This implies that you visit a psychologist regularly.

If you say `I visit a psychologist at 3:00 PM today` - you plan to visit a psychologist based on your previous arrangement.

Comment: And what's about the 2nd paragraph? A temporary activity, even if it is not happening at the time when we are talkin.

Comment: @ProstoCoder that's a good question. I think you use *Present Simple* in the second case because it's part of your schedule but you may not be determined to fulfill it.  However, if you say *I'm visiting a psychologist*, it implies you're determined to see him and you will do so.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I guess you talked about arrangements for future events. When I'm telling "I am visiting a psychologist." I want to tell to somebody about this like a temporary activity that is not happening at the time when we are talking. Is such an example possible?

Comment: @ProstoCoder You can. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, Anatolii!

Answer (score 0):

There're multiple usages of Present Continuous Tense:
1. Something you're doing RIGHT NOW: e.g. I'm watching TV.
2. (Extremely) Near future: e.g. I'm visiting a museum this afternoon. I'm coming.
3. Habituals, recurring events with the emphasis on its CURRENT implementation: e.g. I'm studying French.
Obviously, different verbs prefer different interpretations. Usage 1 is default interpretation, and Usage 2 & 3 generally need extra adverb/context to help interpretation, or are simply idiomatic (as in "I'm coming").